# How to programmatically add Security to a Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I´m using spring-security-tiger-2.0.5.

Is there a way to programmatically add a security proxy to a Spring Bean?

I´m constructing the bean through BeanDefinitionBuilder, and i´d like to add same behaviour as the @Secured annotation.

The roleName´s @Secured equivalent will be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically inject the Spring Security functionality into existing beans, you may need to use a Spring Security applicaton context and register your beans there:

```
@Test
public void testSpringSecurity() throws Exception {
    InMemoryXmlApplicationContext ctx = initSpringAndSpringSecurity();

    // Creates new instance
    IMyService secured = (IMyService) ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .initializeBean(new MyService(), "myService");

    assertTrue(AopUtils.isAopProxy(secured));

    fakeSecurityContext("ROLE_USER");
    secured.getCustomers(); // Works: @Secured("ROLE_USER")

    fakeSecurityContext("ROLE_FOO");
    try {
        secured.getCustomers(); // Throws AccessDenied Exception
        fail("AccessDeniedException expected");
    } catch (AccessDeniedException expected) {
    }
}

private InMemoryXmlApplicationContext initSpringAndSpringSecurity() {
    InMemoryXmlApplicationContext ctx = new InMemoryXmlApplicationContext(
            "<b:bean id='authenticationManager' class='org.springframework.security.MockAuthenticationManager' /> "
                    + "<b:bean id='accessDecisionManager' class='org.springframework.security.vote.UnanimousBased'><b:property name='decisionVoters'><b:list><b:bean class='org.springframework.security.vote.RoleVoter'/></b:list></b:property></b:bean>"
                    + "<b:bean id='objectDefinitionSource' class='org.springframework.security.annotation.SecuredMethodDefinitionSource' /> "
                    + "<b:bean id='autoproxy' class='org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator'/>"
                    + "<b:bean id='methodSecurityAdvisor' class='org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodDefinitionSourceAdvisor' autowire='constructor'/>"
                    + "<b:bean id='securityInterceptor' class='org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor'><b:property name='authenticationManager' ref='authenticationManager' /><b:property name='accessDecisionManager' ref='accessDecisionManager' /><b:property name='objectDefinitionSource' ref='objectDefinitionSource' /></b:bean>");
    return ctx;
}
```

I used an in-memory application context, as the `MethodDefinitionSourceAdvisor` states in its documentation that auto-proxying is only enabled for `ApplicationContext`s. Thus, i belief that you need an app context for auto-proxying, if you don't use a separate `ProxyFactoryBean` for each service object. But since you're using the `@Secured` annotation, i suspect that this is the same as auto-proxying.

The `fakeSecurityContext()` just set an `Authentication` object with the given role into the `SecurityContextHolder` for testing purposes.

You can do it with Spring Core functionality on your own. Assume you've got a service which returns a List of Customers and the current user may only view Customers with up to a specific limit of revenue. The following test case will be our start:

```
@Test
public void testSecurity() throws Exception {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring.xml");
    IMyService service = (IMyService) appCtx.getBean("secured",
            IMyService.class);
    assertEquals(1, service.getCustomers().size());
}
```

This is the original service implementation:

```
public class MyService implements IMyService {

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Customer(100000), new Customer(5000));
    }

}
```

Configure your service object in `spring.xml` and add the method interceptor:

```
<bean id="service" class="de.mhaller.spring.MyService"></bean>

<bean id="securityInterceptor" class="de.mhaller.spring.MyServiceInterceptor">
    <property name="revenueLimit" value="50000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="secured" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetName" value="service" />
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>securityInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The security interceptor implementation:

```
public class MyServiceInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    private int revenueLimit = 10000;
    public void setRevenueLimit(int revenueLimit) {
        this.revenueLimit = revenueLimit;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
        List<Customer> filtered = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        List<Customer> result = (List<Customer>) mi.proceed();
        for (Customer customer : result) {
            if (customer.isRevenueBelow(revenueLimit)) {
                filtered.add(customer);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }

}
```

The advantage of using such an approach is that you not only can check declaratively for roles of the current user, but also enforce corporate policies in a dynamic way, e.g. limit the returned Objects based on business values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice answer, but what i´m looking for is a little bit different.

I´m using spring-security, with pointcut-based interceptors, so that only some roles are allowed for a given method invocation.

My Services, are being registered into spring programmatically, so i cannot use the ApplicationContext approach.

I don´t want to re-implement spring-security funcionality in my own proxy, but to use it the same way as it was declared in the applicationContext, but creating it programmatically.

TKS.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the answers, but I finnally got it working in a totally programatic way.It wasn´t an easy solution, but I´d like to share It.

First of all, I could split the problem into 2 parts:

1) Create the proxy for my own beans.

2) Add the security-roles to every bean. Unfortunately, i couldn´t add a xml-based pointcut, as the beans were all of the same class (a generic service). I wanted a way to secure each bean in a different way, despite they were all the same class.
I decided to use the same declaration used by aopalliance ((execution *.* etc...)

For whom it may interest, this is how I done:

1) Used spring´s BeanNameAutoProxyCreator class, for creating the proxies around the classes i have manually added:

```
private void addProxies(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, List<String> exportedServices) {
  List<String> interceptorNames = findInterceptorNames(beanFactory);
  BeanNameAutoProxyCreator beanPostProcessor = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
  beanPostProcessor.setBeanNames(exportedServices.toArray(new String[exportedServices.size()]));
  beanPostProcessor.setInterceptorNames(interceptorNames.toArray(new String[interceptorNames.size()]));
  beanPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
  beanPostProcessor.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
  beanFactory.addBeanPostProcessor(beanPostProcessor);
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 private List<String> findInterceptorNames(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
  List<String> interceptorNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<? extends Advisor> list = new BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper(beanFactory).findAdvisorBeans();
  for (Advisor ad : list) {
   Advice advice = ad.getAdvice();
   if (advice instanceof MethodInterceptor) {
    Map<String, ?> beansOfType = beanFactory.getBeansOfType(advice.getClass());
    for (String name : beansOfType.keySet()) {
     interceptorNames.add(name);
    }
   }
  }
  return interceptorNames;
 }
```

- where exportedServices stands for the beans i wished to proxy
- The beanFactory instance could be fetched using my own implementation of BeanFactoryPostProcessor

2) For the parameterizable secured-like part:

Created a implementation of spring´s MethodDefinitionSource. implementors of this interface are used by MethodSecurityProxy to fetch securedObjects at runtime.

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
 public ConfigAttributeDefinition getAttributes(Object object) throws                                              IllegalArgumentException {
 if (!(object instanceof ReflectiveMethodInvocation)) {
  return null;
 }
 ReflectiveMethodInvocation invokation = (ReflectiveMethodInvocation) object;
 if (!(invokation.getThis() instanceof MyService)) {
  return null;
 }
 MyService service = (MyService) invokation.getThis();
  Map<String, String> map =getProtectedServiceMethodMap(service);
  String roles = map.get(MethodKeyGenerator.generate(invokation.getMethod()));
  return roles == null ? null : new ConfigAttributeDefinition(StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(roles, ","));
 }
```

- Note that I had to put in a cache the methods wich I wanted to secure for each object instance.

The trickiest part was to register my MethodDefinitionSource impl into the applicationContext, so that the MethodSecurityInterceptor became aware of it:

```
   private void addCrudDefinitionSource() {
 DelegatingMethodDefinitionSource source = (DelegatingMethodDefinitionSource)    beanFactory.getBean(BeanIds.DELEGATING_METHOD_DEFINITION_SOURCE);
     try {
     Field field = source.getClass().getDeclaredField("methodDefinitionSources");
     field.setAccessible(true);
     List list = (List) field.get(source);
     list.add(new MyMethodDefinitionSource());
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
            }
```

Last, for checking Method entrypoints in a aop-style I used code like the following:

```
  private void addToCache(){ // Ommiting parameters
     PointcutExpression expression = parser.parsePointcutExpression(fullExpression);
     Method[] methods = clazzToCheck.getMethods();
     for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
     Method currentMethod = methods[i];
     boolean matches = expression.matchesMethodExecution(currentMethod).alwaysMatches();
     if (matches){
 //Add to Cache
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check out the org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory
class. Wrap your bean with ProxyFactory and add the security interceptor

Comment: I´ve already seen this class, but couldn´t manage to add the security interceptor the right way.

1) What is the correct class? (I´ve tried MethodSecurityInterceptor)
2) How to set the correct ROLES?

Tks.

Comment: It should be something like : new ProxyFactory(new YourBean()).addAdvice(new MethodSecurityInterceptor()); and YourBean's methods has to be annotated with @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")

Comment: OK, but my bean cannot be annotated with @Secured, because the roleName is passed as a parameter (Sometimes "ADMIN", sometimes "USER", etc...)

tks.

Comment: than may be you should check-out something like seam has, you could do like; @Secured("#{user.roles}")